# cURL POST data Problem

Tags: php, curl

im bizzare and im new in stackoverflow , i have some problem and that's :

im sending some page directly to a page and page answer to my request correctly , but i when to try send post data using cURL by php , the page do not react anywhere:

```
<form action="http://remotehost.com/index.aspx" method="post"> -> its work correctly and the index.php show me what i want but when : 

<form action ="http://localhost/fetch_data.php" mthod="post"> -> 

fetch_data.php: 
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<?php
 print_r($_POST);
 $remotehost_cgi = 'http://remotehost.com/index.aspx';
 $ret = post_data($_POST, $remotehost_cgi);
 echo $ret;



?>

<?php 
function post_data($datatopost,$urltopost){
 $crl = curl_init ($urltopost);
 curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
 curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $returndata = curl_exec ($crl);
 return $returndata;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`mthod="post"` to `method="post"` ?

Comment: hey man r u kidding ? if you can answer my Q please do that , and if you can't please get out of my question page :D okay ?

Comment: I don't get it, POST variable was empty because you made a mistake with method. Have you tried it again? And... no one can answer you question because there isn't any :)

Comment: it just a mistake of spelling ok ? in my original source there is no spelling error ! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`curl_exec()` returns boolean FALSE if the exec failed for any reasons. Instead of just returning your `$returndata`, test it first:

```
...
$returndata = curl_exec($crl);
if ($returndata === FALSE) {
   die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($crl));
}
return($returndata);
```

Since you only echo out this value, you'd never see it, as boolean false will output as a null/empty string.

Comment: hey marc thanks for your note ! but there siomething wrong here !!!! the $returndata returned as true ! but the form and the index.aspx do not act to my requrest !!!! :-?

Comment: Try a few `curl_getinfo()` calls on the $crl handle after you do the exec(), details on the options here: http://php.net/curl_getinfo. See what state the handle is in after it finishes off. Maybe something hinky with the script or the server.